# Why is the mid-afternoon break in a Test Match called the "tea break"?

Tags: cricket

Since when the break between the second and third session of any day of a test match started getting referred to "tea break"?

Although the term is like it has become part of the cricket rule book, it could have been referred to "drinks break" or "coffee break" but who decided it to be referred to as what we know today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since forever, effectively.

The important point here is that you have the wrong meaning of tea - it is not about [the drink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea), but [the meal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_(meal)), and in particular "afternoon tea", a light meal taken between lunch and the evening meal. Afternoon tea became established in England in the late 19th century, approximately concurrently with the first Test Match in 1877; as such it was natural to call the mid-afternoon break in the matches a "tea break".